# Javascript, Ajax навигация по фотографиям

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Доброго дня. Через ajax запрос получаю в 'data', массив ссылок из 20-ти фотографий. Каждая фотография лежит в data[индекс].filename

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: "/archiv/foto/",
  data: {'list_id' : list_id
        },
    success: function(data) {
     data = JSON.parse(data);
     }
});
```

Ответ от скрипта /archiv/foto/:

```
foreach($record as $file){
$arr[] = array('filename' => $file["filename"]);
 }
 echo json_encode($arr);
```

Каким образом можно отобразить в блоке `<div id="list_photo">` первую фотографию, а при клике по ней менять изображение на следующую по списку в массиве?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
success: function(data) {
  var data1 = JSON.parse(data);
  if (data1.length > 0) {
    var currentIndex = 0;
    $("#list_photo").html("<img src='#'/>");
    $("#list_photo > img").click(function(){
      if (currentIndex >= data1.length)
        currentIndex = 0;
      $(this).attr("src", data1[currentIndex++].filename); 
    });
    $("#list_photo > img").click();
  }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, попробую оба метода.

Comment: Ваш метод подошёл. Вы не подскажите, как после просмотра последнего элемента массива при клике можно снова попасть на первое фото массива и просмотреть опять по кругу?

Comment: @ВалерийОрлов Добавил в код.

Answer (score 1):

```
var key = 0;
$('#list_photo img').attr('src', $arr[key]);
// Добавьте в див тэг img
$('#list_photo img').click(function(){
key++;
$('#list_photo img').attr('src', $arr[key]);
})
```

Comment: Спасибо, буду сейчас разбираться!

Comment: .filename добавить надо)  при указание атрибута src